# how to generate a dynamic summary table based on selected feature in the main data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hi I have a data frame that is the result of clustering. An example is shown below:

```
        ave_remark_best ave_price_per_sqft    ave_age    ave_DOM ave_activity_rate cluster
1006332      1.00000000          1419.6900 12.0000000   7.000000         1.0000000       3
1010660      1.00000000           912.1800  7.0000000  10.000000         1.0000000       3
1012960      0.00000000           600.7400 26.3000000  36.100000         1.6666667       2
1013515      0.25000000           673.8725  9.7500000  10.500000         0.6666667       4
1014490      0.00000000           439.4600 31.0000000 104.000000         1.0000000       2
1018326      0.00000000           922.5500 12.0000000  10.000000         1.0000000       4
1018446      0.25000000           717.8285 16.0375000  30.387500        10.0000000       1
```

In order to check resulted clusters, I want to have a **function** to create a summary table of all these features for each cluster, so I ran the code shown below:

```
cluster_summary <- agent_temp %>% group_by(cluster) %>% summarise(n=n(),
                                                                  ave_activity_rate_c=mean(ave_activity_rate),
                                                                  ave_DOM_c =mean(ave_DOM),
                                                                  ave_age_c=mean(ave_age),
                                                                  ave_remark_best_c=mean(ave_remark_best),
                                                                  ave_price_per_sqft_c= mean(ave_price_per_sqft))
```

so except **n**, each feature in this table has the name of **variable+"_c"** at the end.

Now I want to automate this process by using a function; however, I am not sure how I can make this function **dynamic** so it automatically generates the column based on available columns. So basiccaly, if the main data frame is now like the one shown below:

```
        ave_remark_best ave_price_per_sqft    ave_age   cluster
1006332      1.00000000          1419.6900 12.0000000     3
1010660      1.00000000           912.1800  7.0000000     3
1012960      0.00000000           600.7400 26.3000000     2
1013515      0.25000000           673.8725  9.7500000     4
1014490      0.00000000           439.4600 31.0000000     2
1018326      0.00000000           922.5500 12.0000000     4
1018446      0.25000000           717.8285 16.0375000     1
```

so it only generates a summary table with **n**, **ave_remark_best**, **ave_price_per_sqft**, **ave_age**.
How can I do this?

So basically, my main challenge is how to find which columns exist in the main data frame so I `group_by` by those columns and create the summary.

Definitely, the function should start like this:

```
cluster_summary_generator <- function (agent_sel, kout){
 
  agent_temp<-agent_sel                      
  agent_temp$cluster <- as.factor(kout$cluster)
  cluster_summary <- agent_temp %>% group_by(cluster) %>% .......
}
```

but I don't know how to complete this

Comment: Do you want to apply `mean` function to all available columns in the dataframe except `cluster` ?

Comment: The functions should be able to work on both data frames that I showed in the example (one data frame has extra two features). I just showed to version so I clarify that columns name may change, so the function should be able to automatically recognize this and create the summary based on columns that are available in the data frame

Comment: @RonakShah, yes, basically, first I want to group by cluster and then apply to mean, so I calculate the mean value for each cluster. The main challenge for me is that the function should able to be applied to a data frame dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cluster column is always called `cluster` you can use :

```
library(dplyr)
cluster_summary_generator <- function (agent_sel){
  agent_sel %>% 
    group_by(cluster) %>% 
    summarise(across(.fns = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
}

cluster_summary_generator(df)
```

If cluster column can change across datasets you can pass that as an argument to the function.

```
cluster_summary_generator <- function (agent_sel, cl){
  agent_sel %>% 
    group_by({{cl}}) %>% 
    summarise(across(.fns = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
}

cluster_summary_generator(df, cluster)
```

This will return mean for every column in the dataframe for each `cluster` irrespective of number of columns.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. Can you explain what `.fns = mean` is doing in the code?

Comment: `across` has two main arguments, `.cols` and `.fns`. `.cols` specify on which column do we want to apply a function and `.fns` is the function to be applied. `.cols` is by default applied to every column in the dataframe so I did not mention it. Here as we want `mean` to be applied to every columns we specify `.fns = mean`.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate. It can pass both unquoted and quoted

```
cluster_summary_generator <- function (agent_sel, cl){
 agent_sel %>% 
    group_by(!! rlang::ensym(cl)) %>% 
     summarise(across(.fns = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
 }

cluster_summary_generator(df, cluster)
cluster_summary_generator(df, "cluster")
```